# Run a script with an interactive prompt on login

Tags: script, powershell, windows-server-2012

I am trying to run a script in Windows Server 2012 on login. I used the group policy editor to assign a .ps1 powershell script which runs fine. However it does not get assigned a command prompt. I would like to watch the script execute and interact with it (contains a long running programming).

Comment: Might check this question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8050298/powershell-logon-script-is-it-possible-to-show-dialog-to-user-or-read-some-user

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with cmd

`cmd /C powershell script.ps1`

That will open the powershell script in a command line window

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this doesn't work, Shawns link above does.